# Find a function $f$

Tags: calculus

I am having a problem with this exercise. Please help.

Is it possible to find a function $f$ with a continuous derivative $f'$, such that $f'(x)>0$ and

1. $f(0)=1,\;f(1)=0$,
2. $f(0)=-1,\;f(1)=0$?

If yes give an example, and if not, show why

Please help

Comment: For (1) look up Rolle's Theorem. For (2) there's many choices, one of which is a linear y=mx+b.

Comment: How can I use Rolle's theorem if we don't have anywhere f(a)=f(b) ?

Comment: How do I use it then here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to (1) is probably most easily obtained using the [mean value theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem), which is a generalization of Rolle's theorem.

As noted in the comments, there are plenty of suitable examples for (2).  In particular, a straight line passing through those two points will do.

Answer (score 1):

1. By Lagrange mean -value theorem there exists $0<\tau<1$ such that 
   $$
   f'(\tau)=\frac{f(1)-f(0)}{1-0}=-1,
   $$
   which is a contradiction. So there is no such function.
2. (Hint). Find a linear function.